# Putting two variables next to each other

Tags: php

I inherited some code and am trying to make sense of this. The only time I have seen syntax like this (putting something in parentheses next to a variable) is in type casting. I can't see any instance of $var2 yet (probably in a script calling the function somewhere). What could this be?

Here is what I see in the code:

```
$var1 = $arrayName['element']($var2);
```

Comment: `$var2` might be created per reference, if the named function was declared like `function xyz( & $output);`

Comment: @mario - If that's the way it was done, the original author of this code should be fired.

Comment: @Joseph ... or forced to maintain it for all eternity. Though there are some useful cases for references, this looks fiddly indeed.

Comment: @mario - ...not for using references, but for using both a reference *and* a return value in the same function.

Comment: Guys, stop speculating about the motive of the original author if all you know is one single paraphrased line of code, as told by an unexperienced coder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is calling a function from the array. It's stored in the array either as a string with the function's name, or [the function itself is stored in there](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php).

Comment: Not actually an anonymous function. It might be just a function name

Comment: Thanks, I see the function declaration now. Didn't think to look for it--was expecting a string value.